# как передать данные в заголовке SOAP-запроса

Tags: node.js, soap

Реализую на node.js soap-клиент для сервера, написанного не мной.

Есть там один метод, данные по которому предполагается передавать вот так: (скриншот из SoapUI, там всё работает)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть передать некую строку в заголовке authenticate.

Я использую пакет node-soap и никак не пойму, как мне сформировать такой пакет.

Пробовал использовать addSoapHeader, но это не помогло.

Comment: И какой запрос получился с добавлением вызова addSoapHeader ?

Comment: Не знаю... Я бился, потом плюнул, переделал на прямую передачу по http
помогла эта статья
https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/supported-api-frameworks/making-soap-requests/

Comment: у меня есть такой кейс использования `soap_client.addSoapHeader({Auth: {username, password_md5}});`

Comment: Да, но там все немножко через одно место. Мы в заголовке передаём только некий токен, который был нам выдан ранее.